# Can gnuplot take a file as an argument

Tags: gnuplot

I have several different files (aaa.dat, bbb.dat ....), is there a way that gnuplot takes these files like DATAFILE_A = file ('aaa.dat'), DATAFILE_B = file ('bbb.dat') so I can recall them easily throughout the script and only change the name of the file at the beginning of the script.

Answer (score 1):

The most convenient way is to have a string, which contains all file names separated by a space. Then you can iterate over this list:

```
filelist = "aaa.dat bbb.dat ccc.dat"
plot for [file in filelist] file
```

or, if you want to create one image for each data file:

```
do for [file in filelist] {
    set output file.'.png'
    plot file
}
```

You can also create the file list using system commands to select some files:

```
filelist = system('ls *.dat')
...
```

Or pass the file list as option when calling `gnuplot`:

```
gnuplot -e "filelist='aaa.dat bbb.dat ccc.dat'" script.gp
```

where `script.gp` contains the generic plotting commands:

```
do for [file in filelist] { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks but I need the info within the file not just the name of the string file - i.e. if the file contains 4 columns of data I would like to be able to recall x,y z,t throughout the script

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean. Could you please extend your question to clarify? If you need a file name at several places, you can also use e.g. `file = word(filelist, 1)` to extract a single file name. Of course you can still use `using` and all that stuff to select different columns. So, whats wrong with this approach?

Comment: what I mean is not just the file name but the content of it (i.e. 0       0       11.209  0.010
250     0       11.122  0.010........)

Comment: Well, then you should definitely rewrite your question and show more much information about what you really need, what you have tried, etc.

Comment: for example I have file A with (x,y,z,z_error) data and file B with (x,y,z,z_error) data that I use throughout a script. Then I got two new file C and D that I would like just to input at the start of the script without having to change throughout the entire script the input filenames (i.e here file name A and filename B)...

Comment: Just specify those file names when calling gnuplot with the script: `gnuplot -e "fileA='aaa.dat'; fileB='bbb.dat'" script.gp`. That just defines the two variables `fileA` and `fileB`, which can be used in the script.